# Options rotate in /etc/resolv.conf is not working for kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, dns, resolve, domain-name, coredns

I have added one more nameserver and also rotate options so that for dns resolution, different name servers are picked using round robin fashion but it's picking first name server always. This is my resolv.conf

```
nameserver 10.96.0.10
nameserver 8.8.8.8
search measurement.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options rotate timeout:1 ndots:5
```

Second nameserver is never getting picked. I tried running nslookup  from kuberenetes pod multiple times. It's always picking first one and that's some cluster level default. Is there some additional configuration change required at k8s level or it has something to do with Coredns policy?
I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify multiple name servers in `resolv.conf` file with options rotate, the resolver library should rotate through each name server in order for each DNS query. However in your case, the second nameserver is being ignored.

This issue could be caused by several factors:

1. Check if the second nameserver is configured correctly and is reachable.
2. Ensure the network connectivity is not an issue and check network configuration and firewall settings.
3. The issue might be caused by DNS caching also. The first name server could be cached and the resolver library might be using a cached response instead of rotating to the next server. Clear the DNS cache to see if it resolves the issue.
4. Also, try to increase the timeout value in options timeout : 3 or 5 seconds. The first server might be responding faster than the second server, so the resolver library is continuously using the first one.

Comment: First name server is IP of coreDns which k8s is setting by default. Also, few comments: 
 1) I just tried to test a simple scenario. Use nslookup<some wrong url>, behaviour should be it should hit first dnsServer, once that fails, it should attempt second dnsServer but it never tries using second dnsServer. 2) How can I clear DNS cache of coredns Pod?

Comment: You can clear the cache of coredns pod by running pkill - HUP coredns. This command sends a hangup signal to the coredns process, which causes it to reload and its configuration and clear the DNS cache. Now you can test if the issue still persists with the options rotate directive.

Comment: Hi @Bhavya Sharma, I have been looking for your response whether the info shared by me was helpful to you. I am glad to assist you further if you have any additional queries or the issue still persists